# automatic scroll down on search

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jsp page in which there are some contents which are hidden.

`onclick` of the search button I have displays much content.

But I want an automatic scroll down so that user doen't have to take the burden to scroll down.

I hope I was

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/improved-animated-scrolling-script-for-same-page-links

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#search_button').click(function () {
  var offset = $('#element_where_you_want_to_scroll_to').offset().top;
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: offset
  }, 100);
});
```

Comment: Using `$('html,body').animate()` makes Opera scroll each one separately... check out this [simple fix](http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/01/18/jquery-smooth-scroll-bugs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this function it will scroll down to the level of ELEMENT that you are displaying for search.

```
// clicking the "down" button will make the page scroll to the $elem's height
$('#elem').click(
    function (e) {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $elem.height()}, 800);
    }
);
```